# How to read this C code? exsam preparing

Tags: c

I am a local programmer in Denmark trying to help a friend out with his C exsam.

He needs to learn to read certain code designs, like this one. However I cannot make head or tails in where the results come from... someone please help me understand it, so I can help him out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int func1(int);
void func2(int(*fp)(int), int);
void main(){
    int (*fp)(int);
    fp = func1;
    (*fp)(1);
    func2(fp,(*fp)(2));
}
int func1(int arg){
    printf("Func1 %d\n", arg);
    return arg;
}
void func2(int(*fp)(int), int arg){
    printf("Func2 %d\n",arg+fp(arg));
}
```

I know the anser is:
 Func1 1 
 Func1 2 
 Func1 2 
 Func2 4

however why that is! Is way above my paygrade.

I understand that in `void main()` we diffine a int... however this one look wird.

We then call `fp = func1;` that effectively runs `printf("Func1 %d\n", arg);`
the text should be "Func 1 (insert arg here). I cannot see why this give a number 1.

it then does something here `(*fp)(1);` meaby some kind of pointer stuff???

I fail to see why it runs `printf("Func1 %d\n", arg);` 3times in a row and again, where does the numbers come from?

and the rest of the code is no better

Comment: Look at this again: `printf("Func1 %d\n", arg)`. What does it print?

Comment: `int (*fp)(int)` is a pointer to a function that takes an int and returns an int, thus the function signature would be int some_name(int).  On the second line, `fp=func1`, we assign the address of `func1` to `fp` (note that the signature of func1 is `int func1(int)`, which matches the above declaration.  The next line has the effect of invoking func1 with an argument of 1.  I suggest that both of you brush up on function pointers and their uses :).

Answer (score 0):

`int (*fp)(int);` creates a new pointer to a function accepting an integer named `fp`

`fp = func1;` sets `fp` to `func1`

`(*fp)(1);` calls `*fp`, which is `func1`, with `1` => prints `Func1 1`

`func2(fp,(*fp)(2));` calls `*fp`, which is `func1`, with `2`. Then it calls `func2` with the result of that, which is `2`, and `fp` which is currently `2` => prints `Func1 2 Func1 2 Func2 4`

Comment: `int (*fp)(int);` is a pointer to a function accepting an integer and returning an integer, not an int pointer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks! I'm not super sharp with my pointer knowledge. Edited to show that it is a pointer to a funciton

Comment: `int (*fp)(int)` is a pointer to a function that takes an int and returns an int, thus the function signature would be int some_name(int).  On the second line, `fp=func1`, we assign the address of `func1` to `fp` (note that the signature of func1 is `int func1(int)`, which matches the above declaration.  The next line has the effect of invoking func1 with an argument of 1.  I suggest that both of you brush up on function pointers and their uses :).

Answer (score 0):

The most confusing aspect of this code is the convoluted use of function pointers.

`void func2(int(*fp)(int), int);` Is the declaration of a function `func2` that accepts a function pointer named `fp` and an integer as an argument. `fp` is a pointer to a function that accepts an `int` argument and returns an `int`. Since this line is a declaration, it could have been rephrased as `void func2(int(*)(int), int);`. The name of the function pointer is not strictly necessary here (but it will be in the definition later on).

`main` declares a pointer to a function `int (*fp)(int);` and set it to point to `func1`. This is possible because the declaration of `func1` matches the type expected by the pointer.

Then we call the function pointed to by `fp`: `(*fp)(1);`. Notice that the first set of parentheses group the star with the pointer name, instead of the return value of the function. In other words, it says to dereference the pointer and call the function at that location, rather than call the function and dereference the return value.

In most versions of C the pointer notation can be omitted and function pointers can be called as if they were functions themselves. This line could be rewritten as just `fp(1);`. In fact, this is the notation used to call `fp` in `func2`.

Next we call `func2` with `fp (== func1)` and the result of `fp(2)`.

In total, the expected printout (with commented explanations):

```
Func1 1  // (*fp)(1); in main()
Func1 2  // Evaluating the argument (*fp)(2) to func2() in main()
Func1 2  // Evaluating the argument fp(arg) to printf() in func2()
Func2 4  // Printing the result of arg==2 + fp(arg)==2 in func2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking it line by line, with some formatting changes and a couple of corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * Declarations for func1 and func2
 */
int func1(int);
void func2(int(*fp)(int), int);

int main( void )        // main always returns int
{
    int (*fp)(int);     // fp is a *pointer* to a function taking a single int parameter
                        // and returning an int value
    fp = func1;         // assign the *address* of func1 to fp
    (*fp)(1);           // call func1 through the pointer fp with an argument of 1
    func2(fp,(*fp)(2)); // call func1 through fp again with a value of 2;
                        // pass that result, along with the value of fp 
                        // (which is the address of func1) to func2.  
}

/**
 * Print the input argument, return the value of the input argument
 */
int func1(int arg){
    printf("Func1 %d\n", arg);
    return arg;
}

/**
 * Call the function pointed to by fp with the input argument, add the
 * result to the input argument, print out the final value
 */
void func2(int(*fp)(int), int arg){
    printf("Func2 %d\n",arg+fp(arg));
}
```

In the code above, `fp` is a *pointer* to a function taking an `int` parameter and returning an `int` result.  We assign the *address* of `func1` to `fp`, and then we call `func1` *through* the `fp` pointer.  That code is basically equivalent to:

```
int main( void )
{
  func1( 1 );
  func2( func1, func1(2) );
}
```

Function pointers are extremely useful, and a few show up in the standard library, such as for the [`qsort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) library function.